# Alinear texto MuiMenuItem React Mui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design

```
<FormControl fullWidth margin='normal' style={{backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
    <InputLabel >Vinculacion: </InputLabel>
         <Select onChange={(e) => { setVinc_id(e.target.value); setProgress(progress + 10) }} label="Vinculacion" value={vinc_id} >
            {vincus.map(
                vincu => <MenuItem divider key={vincu.id} value={vincu.id} > {vincu.nombre}</MenuItem>          )}
          </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Quiero que el texto de las opciones salga centrado

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL control principal de estilos de `MenuItem` especifica [justifyContent: 'flex-start'](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L16).

Para modificar esto, puedes usar:

```
const MenuItem = withStyles({
  root: {
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
})(MuiMenuItem);
```